# TestNG Test breaks while an Assertions Fails in an Iterator Loop

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Page factory and asserting stuff using Try -- Catch block, but yet the TestNg breaks the class, in case the assertions fail. Why it does so, any ideas, please.

```
while (countryListiterator.hasNext()) {

    searchResultPO toSearchpage = homeTosearch.search(countryListiterator.next());

    try {
        errorCellinSearchpage = driver.findElement(By.xpath(errorCellXpath));
        Assert.assertFalse(errorCellinSearchpage.isDisplayed()));

    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        E.getCause();
        E.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by break the class?

Are you getting Execption becaused errorCellinSearchpage is not displayed?

Comment: No. It actually is displayed, I get java.lang.AssertionError and program stops. Rest of the iteration is uncovered.

Comment: Error java.lang.AssertionError  means assertion failed which can happen only if errorCellinSearchpage.isDisplayed() returns true [Means item is displayed].    I think you should use Assert.assertTrue.

Comment: I actually assertfalse since I'm not expecting that element to be seen in the page - even it it does, the testng class shouldn't break.

Comment: Assert will throw the exception if function returns false.  If you want test to return false do not use Assert but if statement.